# How do I build gitlab-ci pages only on the latest semver tag? Ignoring backport tags/etc

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-tag, semantic-versioning

I want to run the gitlab-ci pages job only if the project is getting a new tag pushed. I already know that you can do this with:

```
only:
  - tags
```

but the issue is that, if we ever push a tag for an older version (a backported bugfix or something) then this would overwrite the pages build. We tag using SEMVER if that helps

For example, what I'm trying to avoid is having a bug fix for an earlier version replacing the gitlab pages.

Let's say on the master branch we release version 1.5.0, this will build the pages for that version, and those will be the current documentation pages.

Now let's say we had to do a bugfix for version 1.3.0 to 1.3.1, if we make that bug fix and then push it, since pages builds on tags, it would build the docs for 1.3.1 and those would replace the docs for 1.5.0, which I want to avoid somehow.

Answer (score 2):

GitLab CI [allows to use regex patterns](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#regular-expressions) with `only`.

In your case, if you want your pipeline to be run only if a new tag is pushed, you should think of a naming convention for tags and find a regex that will only match these new tags. This should give you some ideas:

```
job:
    only:
       - /^(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)$/
    except:
      - branches
      - triggers
```

You need the `except` statement to specify that the job should only run when a tag is pushed. If you just added `- tags` to an `only` statement with a regex, it would run whenever a tag is pushed + when a branch or trigger matches the regex.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately I don't think this satisfies my problem. I have added more explanation to the original post. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to incorporate an beginning stage job that compares the latest tag and only sends `success` if the most recent pushed tag is the latest

```
stages:
  - compare tags
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

job:
  stage: compare tags
  only:
    - <semver tag regex goes here>
  except:
    - branches
  script: 'script-that-will-compare-all-semver-tags-to-CI_COMMIT_TAG-and-fail-if-not-latest'

job:
  stage: build
  ...

job:
  stage: test
  ...

...
```

the whole job should stop if the semver comparison fails